# What kind of scale does my area graph need for the x-axis?

Tags: d3.js

I am making an area graph in D3 that I am testing with 4 points.  The y-axis is a linear scale from 0 to the largest value of data.count.  The x-axis is a time scale that sets the domain with d3.extent - the min & max of data.date. These dates are created from month & year values so they are all the 1st of their month.

Imagine that there are 4 columns in the graph. The x-value for the data points should fall in the center of each column.  This means that the first point would not actually touch the y-axis, as would be normal for an area graph.  The distance from the y-axis to the first point is half a column.

I need to add a data point ON the y-axis so it looks like the data starts somewhere and goes TO the first data point. And I need to add a data point on the right hand edge of the graph so it looks like the data flatlines at the end.

I tried adding those additional start & end points to my data array and giving them appropriate values for date (the 15th of, or halfway through, their respective months).  This gave me 6 points total. BUT, instead of having half a column's width to the left of the first point, and half a column's width to the right of the 4th point, all 6 points were evenly spaced & that's not what I need.

Is there a different type of scale I should use for the x-axis or a different way entirely to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround and would like to share it for anyone else in the same situation.

My first attempt was to simply modify the dates of the first & last elements.  Since each point represented the first of the month but needed to fall in the middle of the columns, I modified the first date to be the 15th of its month and the last date to be the 15th of the previous month instead of the 1st of the next month. This *almost* worked but was slightly off center because some months have 28 or 31 days.

So instead, I changed the x-axis to a linear scale with a range of 0 to the width of the div that wraps the entire area graph.

Then I looped through my data array and added an xval property to each object that was calculated this way:

```
if(i === 0){
    xval = 0;
}else{
    xval = (columnWidth * i) - (columnWidth/2);
}
```

Then, when I calculated the area graph coordinates, I passed xval to .x like this:

```
var area = d3.area()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.xval); })
  .y1(function(d) { return y(d.count); });
area.y0(y(0));
```